# How to fix a rotated output in zoom in region in image?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I want to zoom a portion of an image and insert in the same plot. Right now, I am using mpl_toolkits package to do it. However, it results in a rotating zoom in the region as the below figure. How could I fix it using Python?

This is my full code

```
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import zoomed_inset_axes
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import mark_inset
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import matplotlib.patches as patches

def zoom_in_rec(input, ax,rect, cmap):
    axins = zoomed_inset_axes(ax, 2, loc=3)  
    x1, x2, y1, y2 = rect.get_x(), rect.get_x()+rect.get_width(),rect.get_y(), rect.get_y()+rect.get_height() # specify the limits
    axins.set_xlim(x1, x2)  # apply the x-limits
    axins.set_ylim(y1, y2)  # apply the y-limits
    mark_inset(ax, axins, loc1=3, loc2=4, fc="none", ec="1.0")
    plt.yticks(visible=False)
    plt.xticks(visible=False)
    axins.imshow(input, cmap=cmap)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    img = mpimg.imread('lena.bmp')
    #Plot
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(128,128))
    fig.patch.set_facecolor('white')
    gs1 = gridspec.GridSpec(1,1)
    gs1.update(wspace=0.02, hspace=0.02)  # set the spacing between axes.
    ax1 = plt.subplot(gs1[0])
    ax1.imshow(img,cmap='gray')
    rect1 = patches.Rectangle((200, 200), 120, 80, linewidth=3, edgecolor='r', facecolor='none')
    zoom_in_rec(img, ax1,rect1, cmap='gray')
    plt.show()
```

This is the lena image

[image]

This is my current output
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The coordinate system of an image and the plot are different, the image has a coordinate system whose origin is in the upper left, and the y axis goes upwards downwards, while in the plot the coordinate system is in the lower left, and the y axis goes from bottom to top. to solve we can use the flipud function of numpy:

```
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import zoomed_inset_axes
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import mark_inset
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import numpy as np

def zoom_in_rec(input, ax,rect, cmap):
    axins = zoomed_inset_axes(ax, 2, loc=3)  # zoom-factor: 2.5, location: upper-left
    x1, x2, y1, y2 = rect.get_x(), rect.get_x()+rect.get_width(),rect.get_y(), rect.get_y()+rect.get_height() # specify the limits
    axins.set_xlim(x1, x2)  # apply the x-limits
    axins.set_ylim(y1, y2)  # apply the y-limits
    mark_inset(ax, axins, loc1=3, loc2=4, fc="none", ec="1.0")
    plt.yticks(visible=False)
    plt.xticks(visible=False)
    # flip image
    rot = np.flipud(input)
    axins.imshow(rot, cmap=cmap)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    img = mpimg.imread('/home/eyllanesc/Downloads/lena.png')
    #Plot
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(128,128))
    fig.patch.set_facecolor('white')
    gs1 = gridspec.GridSpec(1,1)
    gs1.update(wspace=0.02, hspace=0.02)  # set the spacing between axes.
    ax1 = plt.subplot(gs1[0])
    ax1.imshow(img,cmap='gray')
    rect1 = patches.Rectangle((200, 200), 120, 80, linewidth=3, edgecolor='r', facecolor='none')
    zoom_in_rec(img, ax1,rect1, cmap='gray')
    plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This is what I expected. Thanks. Do you know how to change the rectangular of zoomed in region to red color, instead of black in current version. Many thanks